# CSS - Setting fixed pixel width alongside max-width property

Tags: html, css

I have a div which contains a `<p/>` tag. The div is a container for a message text. The div should have a width of `200px`, and also a `max-width` of `600px` so that if the message is longer, the div can grow up to `600px`. When implementing this, the width stays at `200px` and the text overflows the `div` instead of the `div` growing in size (up to `600px`)

Here is the code:

```
<div style={{styles.messageBubbleWrapper}}>
    <p>{message.messageText}</p>
</div>

const styles = {
    // styles for the div
     messageBubbleWrapper: {
     width: 200,
     maxWidth: 500,
     padding: 10,
     borderRadius: 10,
     height: "auto",
     maxHeight: 300,
     margin: "35px 0 20px 0",
  },
}
```

I have also changed the `width` property of the `messageBubbleWrapper` to `30%` (`30%` of the parent div which is set to `100%` width) after researching solutions, however this just sets the width to `30%` even if the text is large and overflows the `div`. Any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: You could try a min-width of 200px, width: fit-content, and max-width of 600px. This way the content will always be 200px minimum, it will fit the content between 200 - 600px and then stop growing at 600px

Comment: @MailCarrier Perfect, thank you very much. Could you explain to me why my original code did not work and do the same thing as the solution you described? Thanks

Comment: It's because of your width property. You set a fixed width rather than a variable or dynamic width. The 200px width means 200px regardless of screen size, content, padding, etc. When its dynamic it adjusts based on content. Another common approach is to use width: 100% with a max-width; but, this will cause the container to be at the maximum limit the entire time and then shrink as the page shrinks for mobile responsiveness. Width: fit-content has almost the same properties as width: 100% except its sized based on the contents inside of the container.

Answer (score 2):

You have `width: 200px` and `max-width: 600px`, the max width never kicks in, as the element is set to the width value that is smaller than the max width.

Usually, we use those two properties like this: one value fixed and the other value percentage, i.e `width: 600px` and `max-width: 100%`, it means the element can never go wider than 600px while shrinks as needed such as on a mobile screen.

To fix the layout you asked, you could do:

```
width: fit-content; /* or max-content, or don't set width if not needed */
max-width: 600px;
min-width: 200px;
```

And remember, `min-width` has higher priority than `max-width` has higher priority than `width`.

Answer (score 0):

You directly set the width on the dov to 200. You need to set the `min-width` property and get rid of the width property.